# Is there a library for "linear quadratic regulator" function in C++

Tags: c++, matlab

Is there a library in control, similar to  MATLAB's control toolbox, for C++? Where I could run functions such as linear quadratic regulator (lqr)?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [Matlab Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/)

*MATLAB Coder™ generates standalone C and C++ code from MATLAB® code. The generated source code is portable and readable.*

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old, I would like to point to the following open-source library, which holds a C++ implementation of LQR, iLQR, and others:

https://github.com/ethz-adrl/control-toolbox